# How to run the same function on different sections on a page with same class name

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have function that is calculating the difference between two fields and showing it in the third field. This is working fine. How can I run the same function if I have multiple "mysection" in my html to calculate the difference between fields within each of these sections?

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    var total=$(".field2");
    total.keyup(function(){
 var diff = Number($(".field2").val()) - Number($(".field1").val()); 
   $(".field3").val(diff.toFixed(2));
    }); 
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="mysection">
 <input type="text" name="field1" value="" size="30" maxlength="300" class="field1">
 <input type="text" name="field2" value="" size="30" maxlength="300" class="field2">
 <input type="text" name="field3" value="" size="30" maxlength="300" class="field3">
 </div>
```

Comment: e.g. if my html markup is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `siblings` & `$(this)`. Also delegate the event from the parent that is `div.mysection`.

In this case on key up event `$(this).val()` will get the value for input with `field2` element & `$(this).siblings('.field1').val()` will get the value from the sibling element with this class

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.mysection').on('keyup', '.field2', function() {
    var field2Val = $(this).val();
    let getFieldOne = $(this).siblings('.field1').val();
    var diff = Number(field2Val) - Number(getFieldOne);
    $(this).siblings(".field3").val(diff.toFixed(2));
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="mysection">
  <input type="text" name="field1" value="" size="30" maxlength="300" class="field1">
  <input type="text" name="field2" value="" size="30" maxlength="300" class="field2">
  <input type="text" name="field3" value="" size="30" maxlength="300" class="field3">
</div>

<div class="mysection">
  <input type="text" name="field1" value="" size="30" maxlength="300" class="field1">
  <input type="text" name="field2" value="" size="30" maxlength="300" class="field2">
  <input type="text" name="field3" value="" size="30" maxlength="300" class="field3">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using the div as the selector of all input childs instead of just selecting one.

```
var total=$("div input");
```

You can do it like this instead.

Comment: if my markup is like this
<div class="mysection">
 <input type="text" name="field1" value="" size="30" maxlength="300" class="field1">
 <input type="text" name="field2" value="" size="30" maxlength="300" class="field2">
 <input type="text" name="field3" value="" size="30" maxlength="300" class="field3">
 </div>

Answer (score 0):

## [`$(this).parent()`](https://api.jquery.com/parent/)

If each of your input groups are wrapped in a separate tag (ex. `<fieldset>`) and then everything wrapped in a `<form>` tag:

- Bind the `<form>` to the **keydown** (or **keyup**), **input**, and **change** event.

> > ```
> > $('form').on('keydown input change', ...
> > ```

- Next, assign **[event data](https://api.jquery.com/event.data/)** as a selector of all `<input>`, `<textarea>`, and/or `<select>`

> > ```
> > $('form').on('keydown input change', 'input, textarea, select', function(e) {...
> > ```

- Now `$(this)` will be the clicked<sup>✱</sup> tag if it matches anything in event data parameter (ex. `'input, textarea, select'`). Use the following expression to reference the parent tag of the clicked tag (ex. `<fieldset>`).

> > ```
> > var fieldset = $(this).parent();
> > ```

- Then assign variables to every thing within the parent tag using variations of `set.find()`.

> > ```
> > var A = Number(fieldset.find('.A').val());
> > var B = Number(fieldset.find('.B').val());
> > var O = fieldset.find('.O').val();
> > ...
> > fieldset.find('.C').val(Math.round(100 * C) / 100);
> > ```

<sup><sup>✱</sup>Technically `$(this)` wasn't clicked, `this` keyword is the function owner but the **event data** parameter conveniently treats `$(this)` as `event.target`. In this case, `e.target` is any input, textarea, or select being the event origin of a keydown, input, or change event.</sup>

---

### Demo

**Added extra functionality it can add, divide, and multiply as well as subtract**

```js
$('#calc').on('keydown input change', 'input, select', function(e) {
  var set = $(this).parent();
  var A = Number(set.find('.A').val());
  var B = Number(set.find('.B').val());
  var O = set.find('.O').val();
  var C = 0;
  switch (O) {
    case '-':
      C = A - B;
      break;
    case '+':
      C = A + B;
      break;
    case '*':
      C = A * B;
      break;
    case '/':
      C = A / B;
      break;
    default:
      break;
  }
  set.find('.C').val(Math.round(100 * C) / 100);
});
```

```css
label,
input,
output,
select {
  font: inherit;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  height: 30px;
  line-height: 30px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<form id='calc'>
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Calculation 1</legend>
    <input class="A" type="number" value="0" min='-9999.99' max="9999.99" step='.01'>
    <select class='O'>
      <option value='-'>&minus;</option>
      <option value='+'>&plus;</option>
      <option value='*'>&times;</option>
      <option value='/'>&divide;</option>
    </select>
    <input class="B" type="number" value="0" min='-9999.99' max="9999.99" step='.01'><label>&nbsp;=&nbsp;</label>
    <output class='C'></output>
  </fieldset>

  <fieldset>
    <legend>Calculation 2</legend>
    <input class="A" type="number" value="0" min='-9999.99' max="9999.99" step='.01'>
    <select class='O'>
      <option value='-'>&minus;</option>
      <option value='+'>&plus;</option>
      <option value='*'>&times;</option>
      <option value='/'>&divide;</option>
    </select>
    <input class="B" type="number" value="0" min='-9999.99' max="9999.99" step='.01'><label>&nbsp;=&nbsp;</label>
    <output class='C'></output>
  </fieldset>

  <fieldset>
    <legend>Calculation 3</legend>
    <input class="A" type="number" value="0" min='-9999.99' max="9999.99" step='.01'>
    <select class='O'>
      <option value='-'>&minus;</option>
      <option value='+'>&plus;</option>
      <option value='*'>&times;</option>
      <option value='/'>&divide;</option>
    </select>
    <input class="B" type="number" value="0" min='-9999.99' max="9999.99" step='.01'><label>&nbsp;=&nbsp;</label>
    <output class='C'></output>
  </fieldset>
</form>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```